# How to join node to cluster?

Tags: elixir

I have two nodes up and running, I tried to do `remote_console` to connect to another node, When I try to connect to a node like this:

```
Node.connect :api@ip-10-0-19-179.eu-central-1.compute.internal
```

I get this error:

```
Node.connect :api@ip-10-0-19-179.eu-central-1.compute.internal  
** (CompileError) iex:2: invalid call 179.eu()
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1355: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
```

Any idea?

Comment: First of all you've got a syntax error. Try `Node.connect :"api@ip-10-0-19-179.eu-central-1.compute.internal"`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, I got `false` as a result

Comment: Node.ping returns :pang, but servers can ping each other on terminal..

Comment: Could you please verify the cookies your nodes run with are the same? Try run Node.get_cookie on the nodes and compare 'em.

Comment: Yes, its, actually, the problem was with the hosts file, I had to define the hostname of other node to the ip address of that node